# Getting an error with the python asyncio gather

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, websocket, python-asyncio

I don't know why I keep getting this error, I am trying to gather a websocket and a discord bot. So i can run them from the same file, but I keep getting the error posted below the code. Should I switch to threading or did I just do something wrong

This is where I start the websocket server.

```
async def startWebSocketServer(ip= "localhost", port=5000):

    async def send(websocket, path):
        async for message in websocket:
            await websocket.send(message)     
    start = websockets.serve(send, ip, port) 
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start)
    print(f"Running websocket server at ip: {ip} and port: {port}")
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

This is where I run my discord bot

```
async def runBot():
    ...
    loadExtentions()
    bot.run(TOKEN)

async def main():
    asyncio.gather(startWebSocketServer(), runBot())
    print("Online!")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

This is the output of the code

```
Online!
Loaded Cogs
_GatheringFuture exception was never retrieved
future: <_GatheringFuture finished exception=RuntimeError('Cannot close a running event loop')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 713, in run
    loop.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 314, in run_forever
    assert self._self_reading_future is None
AssertionError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 90, in _cleanup_loop
    _cancel_tasks(loop)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 75, in _cancel_tasks
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True))
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 618, in run_until_complete
    self._check_running()
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 578, in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  File "c:\Users\pc\Desktop\Projects\Cool art bot\main.py", line 63, in runBot
    bot.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 719, in run
    _cleanup_loop(loop)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 95, in _cleanup_loop
    loop.close()
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 674, in close
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot close a running event loop")
RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop
```

Comment: aren't you supposed to use `client.run` when using discord

Comment: I'm using a bot object bot a client object. And you should too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in this code:

```
start = websockets.serve(send, ip, port) 
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start)
print(f"Running websocket server at ip: {ip} and port: {port}")
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

`run_until_complete` and `run_forever` are designed to spin up the event loop *from sync code*. If you're in an async function, `run_until_complete` is spelled simply `await`. While there's no direct equivalent of `run_forever`, it's easy enough to emulate it using any waiting device. For example:

```
await websockets.serve(send, ip, port) 
print(f"Running websocket server at ip: {ip} and port: {port}")
await asyncio.Event().wait()
```

The same applies to `bot.run`, which can be replaced with `bot.start`:

```
async def runBot():
    ...
    loadExtentions()
    await bot.start(TOKEN)
```

Comment: I tried that and I got [another error](https://gyazo.com/ba17ddb3934f0bf107053e37dab9b542) which im pretty sure is the exact sme one.

Comment: @EliteNarNar It's the same problem, since `bot.run()` also tries to run the event loop. You should be able to replace it with `bot.start()` - see edited answer.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, thought it was a discord.py thing. I tried and got [yet another error](https://gyazo.com/9cc7e75ec51b9551d0529dfff382d0fd)

Comment: @EliteNarNar The new error seems like an unrelated issue. It should probably be posted as a separate question, with minimal code that reproduces the error.